# Is it possible to delete a single row using JPA repository where the rows are not unique?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

This is a bad database design.
The table is as follows where both the columns are foreign keys. The design was created by someone else.
I know this is a violation and should not be done. I will be changing the entities.

```
+---------+---------------+
| cart_id |    item_id    |
+---------+---------------+
|       1 |             1 |
|       1 |             1 |
|       1 |             1 |
|       2 |             1 |
|       3 |             1 |
|       3 |             3 |
+---------+---------------+
```

Before changing, I just want to know whether it is possible to delete a single row in this case where the matching results are many.

```
    @Query(value = "delete FROM cart_items where cart_id =:cartId AND item_id =:itemId", nativeQuery = true)
    @Transactional
    int deleteCartItem(long cartId, long itemId);
```

For the above query, it will delete multiple records, I just want to delete single or none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the `LIMIT` clause of SQL. For your case you can use `LIMIT 1` at the end of your query. It's going to delete the first row of your resultset.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes I just checked and it worked. Marked it as accepted. Thank you buddy.

Comment: That is Wonderful! :)